# Creating ios simulator build on iOS8

Tags: ios, facebook, build, ios-simulator, review

I need to create ios simulator build for facebook review, I was step by step with their tutorial, but I cant get over creating that... I've used this comand

```
xcodebuild -arch i386 -sdk iphonesimulator8.0
```

But it says `** BUILD FAILED **`. I have an extension in my app (today extension for iOS8) and it looks like, it's trying to make an build for that extension

> Developer/Feelings/**todayFeed**/TodayViewController.m:10:9: fatal error: 
>         'NotificationCenter/NotificationCenter.h' file not found
>            1 error generated.

Where the "todayFeed" is name of that extension... Have anyone any idea how to do that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution by myself, but for someone who have same problem, here is answer.

I've deleted that extension and than added "i386" architecture to archs in xcode. Than ran again that in terminal and it worked... :-)

Comment: Thanks stepik21. The solution worked. I removed my extension, added i386 architecture. I had two more libraries that weren't supporting simulator build, which I had to remove before making the i386 build.